# Excel autofilter issue where criteria1 range using row column instead of address

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I have a massive macro, what I am trying to reduce, by using a loop structure to replace the current use of hard-coded address with variables. 
One of the statements is using a cell address

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(4, 1).AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Test").Range("c1")
end with
```

I want to use row/column

in this sample where col=3, I am getting a Run-time error '1004' error:

"Application-defined or object defined"

```
.Cells(4, 1).AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Test").Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(1, col))
```

What is the best way to convert addresses to variables, for this usage case.

Comment: One way I found was to create an address using, X1=Cells(1, col).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False, External:=False). This allowed me to replace the "c1" of my example with X1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Cells(4, 1).AutoFilter Field:=36, _
       Criteria1:=Worksheets("Test").Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(1, col))
```

Here the `Range()` is scoped to the "Test" sheet, but the unqualified `Cells()` will refer to the active sheet: if that's not "Test" then you will get a 1004 error.

Since you only have a single-cell range this would work:

```
.Cells(4, 1).AutoFilter Field:=36, _
       Criteria1:=Worksheets("Test").Cells(1, col)
```